# Which is the proper way of using @synchronized?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSArray *array;
```

I don't override a setter and a getter of the array. I could use @synchronized(array){} or @synchronized(self.array){}. As I knows all cases are correct, am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've phrased the question, both statements are equivalent as a matter of concurrency safety strategy.

Depending on the scale and how far you have completed work on your project, you may wish to consider an alternative strategy for thread-safety altogether.

Recently, Apple has made a point of recommending thread-safety-by-serialization rather than traditional blocking. In short, as contention increases, serialized access is far more efficient than blocking with @synchronize.

Rather than synchronize, consider setting up a GCD serial queue and queuing up access to resources shared across threads.

Comment: Or, better, use reader-writer pattern, a GCD concurrent queue, performing reads with `dispatch_sync` and writes with `dispatch_barrier_async`.

Answer (score 12):

Using `@syncrhonized(obj)` just forms a lock so that other code synchronizing on `obj` won't execute at the same time.

Atomic properties work by not allowing changes to be made while a property is being accessed; they provide implicit locking *for access*.

```
array = someObject.array; //locked
[array doSomething];      //no longer locked
```

You can't override getters and setters for `atomic` properties, but using the `@sycnronized` directive around the getter/setter should be sufficient.

```
@synthesize array=_array;

...

-(void)setArray
{
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        _array = array;
    }
}

-(NSArray *)array
{
    NSArray *retVal;

    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        retVal = _array;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Honestly, unless you're doing some seriously multithreaded programming, atomic properties are unnecessary and just cause performance hits.

Comment: Clearly, the examples the getters and setters employing `@synchronized` are a far cry from thread-safety and thus one would almost never apply this pattern. One often has to perform synchronization at a higher-level to realize thread-safety.